# Catch a reraised exception with multiple catch blocks?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I am catching exceptions and for a specific exception class and error code within that class I do some custom handling.  For all other exceptions, I want to use the generic error handler.  Like such:

```
on E:EADSDatabaseError  do
  begin
    case E.ACEErrorCode of
      5132: 
        begin
        //Custom handling
        end;    
      else
        begin
          raise;
        end;
    end;
  end;
on E:Exception do
  begin
    //usual handling
  end;
```

For most codes in the original error,  I want to fall through to the generic error handler.  However, reraising it does not seem to allow the more general exception class handler to fire. (I'm not sure I would expect it to.  I've never done this sort of thing before.)

Is my best option to have two `try/excepts`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can see 3 possible solutions,

- what you said, two try except block
- put your usual handling code to a procedure, and call it from both places
- something like this

  ```
  on E:Exception do
  begin
    if ( e is EADSDatabaseError ) and
       ( EADSDatabaseError(e).ACEErrorCode = 5132 then
    begin
      //Custom handling
    end else
    begin
     //usual handling
    end;
  end;
  ```

in this case I would use the third one.